# Two diagonals of a regular nonagon (a $9$-sided polygon) are chosen. What is the probability that their intersection lies inside the nonagon?

Tags: combinatorics, geometric-probability

Two diagonals of a regular nonagon (a $9$-sided polygon) are chosen. What is the probability that their intersection lies inside the nonagon?

This is similar to a previous problem that I posted about a dodecahedron. However, this provides more difficult, as a nonagon is  (in my opinion) more difficult to work with than a dodecahedron. A dodecahedron, in every sense of the object, is even (even edges, even vertices...). This cannot be said for the $2D$ Nonagon.

Here is what I'm thinking. Draw a nonagon. Find all of the intersection points of the nonagon. A quick glance at online diagram of a nonagon (with diagonals drawn) shows that this method would fall flat quickly. Finding all of the intersection points can be found with $\binom{9}{4}=126$. This means that $126$ is the numerator. If only I could find the denominator....

Help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I also know that there are $27$ diagonals in a regular nonagon. I think that the denominator would be $\binom{27}{2}=351$. This means that the answer would be $\frac{14}{39}$. Can someone verify this or correct me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are $27$ diagonals in a convex nonagon $P$, and you can choose $2$ of them in ${27\choose 2}=351$ ways. In order to intersect in the interior of $P$ the two diagonals have to have different endpoints, a total of four. Conversely any four vertices of $P$ determine exactly one pair of diagonals intersecting in the interior of $P$, hence there are ${9\choose4}=126$ such pairs. The probability in question therefore is ${126\over351}={14\over39}$.

Comment: Note that this method generalizes easily to an arbitrary $n$-gon:  it has ${n \choose 2} - n = \frac{1}{2}n(n-3)$ interior diagonals, and there are ${n \choose 4}$ pairs of diagonals that intersect.  This means that the OP's concerns about the number of vertices being even or odd is moot.

Answer (score 3):

<s>There are $\frac{9\cdot(9-3)}{2}=27$ diagonals in a nonagon. There are 27C2 ways to choose two diagonals, which is $351$. This is our denominator.
The only way the diagonals can intersect inside the nonagon is if they share an endpoint. For each diagonal, there are $5$ other diagonals that share one endpoint, and 5 that share the other for a total of $10$ ways for a certain diagonal to share an endpoint with another. $27$ diagonals means $\frac{10\cdot27}{2}=135$ ways to have adjacent diagonals. The probability for the diagonals to intersect is $\frac{135}{351}=\frac{5}{13}$.
Taking the complement of this gives us an answer of $\frac{8}{13}$.</s>

The question appears to be somewhat vague in the phrase, "their [two diagonals'] intersection"; two diagonals of a nonagon do not necessarily have to intersect.

If the question means to ask for the probability of two uniformly randomly chosen diagonals intersecting inside (but not on) the nonagon, see [Christian Blatter's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2668979/533960).

This answer answers a different question than what is presumably being asked.

Comment: This is not correct.  If you number the vertices $1$ to $9$, the diagonals $1-3$ and $4-8$ do not intersect inside the nonagon.

Comment: This is still not correct.  Diagonals $1-5$ and $2-6$ intersect within the nonagon and do not share an endpoint.  If they share an endpoint they cannot intersect.

Comment: Ross. Can you provide a solution that patches up on Jeffrey's?

Comment: You made me realize that I was assuming all the endpoints were distinct, which OP did not specify.

Answer (score 1):

Call the points $1$ through $9$ clockwise.  The first point can be $1$ by symmetry and the second can be $3,4,5$.  If it is $3$ the diagonals cross if $2$ is a point of the other diagonal, which is $6$ of the $26$ choices.  If the second point is $4$ the diagonals cross if one point is $2,3$ and the other is $5-9$, which is $10$ of the $26$.  If the second point is $5$ the diagonals cross if one is $2-4$ and the other is $6-9$, which is $12$ cases of $26$.  The overall probability is $\frac 13\cdot \frac {6+10+12}{26}=\frac {28}{78}=\frac {14}{39}$

This agrees with your $\frac {126}{351}$, which is correct.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is incorrect.

Comment: @APiercingArrow:  It would be more helpful if you would point out what you think is the problem.  I could then consider your argument.  That is what I did in my comments to Jeffrey H. and my first paragraph.

Comment: Your edited answer is a bit confusing;  the first and last sentence currently contradict each other.